# Issue connecting to sql database from eclipse project?

Tags: java, php, mysql, sql, eclipse

I'm trying to retrieve info from a basic database I made using [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/).  Here's what the created db (testdb_vfk) looks like in MAMP:

[image]

And here is my java code to connect and retrieve from it:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        //Accessing driver from the JAR file
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        //Creating a variable for the connection called "con"
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8888/testdb_vfk","root","root");
        //jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee_record --> This is the database
        // root is the database user
        // root is the password

        // here we create our query
        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select * from name");

        // Creating a variable to execute query
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

        while(result.next()){
            System.out.println(result.getString(1) + " " + result.getString(2));
            // getString returns the data
            // 1 is the first field in the table
            // 2 is the second field
        }
    }
}
```

**However**, I'm getting this error whenever I try to run it:

[image]

Any ideas on why I can't connect?

EDIT:  here's my url:

[image]

Comment: MySQL usually run on port 3306. Are you sure you should replace it with 8888? Something tells me that `8888` may be port on which you are communicating with server via browser (which provides tools to manage database). Database run on 3306 port and this port is internally also used by server to communicate with it.

Comment: @Pshemo  oops, sorry!  I included the url now, see my edit above.  it fails when I replace it with 3306 also though

Comment: You are confusing ports. Via 8888 you are able to communicate with server which is generating HTML for your browser, which allows you to manage database. But server and database are two separate applications. Server simply internally is also using 3306 port to connect and actually manage database.

Comment: @Pshemo  gotcha.  Changed the local host. Still receiving communication errors when trying to run though

Comment: OK, based on https://www.mamp.info/en/documentation/#q6 it seems that MySQL is running on port 8889. Try with `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/testdb_vfk","root","root")`.

Comment: @Pshemo this did it! Thanks!